# How to make --no-packages-dir the default for dart pub in WebStorm?

Tags: dart, webstorm, dart-pub

Dart 1.19.0-dev supports a new flag **--no-packages-dir** that replaces --no-package-symlinks.  Is there any way to make this the default in WebStorm?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way.
We have to wait until it becomes the default in `pub`

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18006